# How to generate URL basis on when the program is running?

Tags: java, date, url, stringbuilder

I am trying to generate an URL basis on when I am running my program. Below is my hardcoded url as of now -

```
private static final String TRANSACTION_URL = "http://mon.vip.host.com/reports/podding/Transaction?startTime=2014/07/30 00:00&endTime=2014/07/30 20:00&defaultDim=Name&defaultDim=Type&metric=TransactionDuration&percentile=95";
```

So suppose if I am running my program on July 30th, then `startTime` should be

```
startTime=2014/07/30 00:00
```

And `endTime` should be the current hour in which the program is running as of now -

```
endTime=2014/07/30 23:00
```

So the full url will become then as  -

```
private static final String TRANSACTION_URL = "http://mon.vip.host.com/reports/podding/Transaction?startTime=2014/07/30 00:00&endTime=2014/07/30 23:00&defaultDim=Name&defaultDim=Type&metric=TransactionDuration&percentile=95";
```

but if I am running my  program on July 31st then `startTime` should be

```
startTime=2014/07/31 00:00
```

And `endTime` should be the current hour in which the program is running as of now -

```
endTime=2014/07/31 01:00 (suppose for now)
```

Then the full url will be -

```
private static final String TRANSACTION_URL = "http://mon.vip.host.com/reports/podding/Transaction?startTime=2014/07/31 00:00&endTime=2014/07/31 01:00&defaultDim=Name&defaultDim=Type&metric=TransactionDuration&percentile=95";
```

Below is my code which is using the hardcoded url for now -

```
private static final String TRANSACTION_URL = "http://mon.vip.host.com/reports/podding/Transaction?startTime=2014/07/30 00:00&endTime=2014/07/30 20:00&defaultDim=Name&defaultDim=Type&metric=TransactionDuration&percentile=95";   

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // I am suppose to generate proper TRANSACTION_URL here and then pass to loadMetrics method

    List<ClientMetrics> clientMetrics = loadMetrics(TRANSACTION_URL);

    // some code here
}   

private static List<ClientMetrics> loadMetrics(String url) {
    String jsonString = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
    // some code here
}
```

How do I approach this to make the right url depending on when I am running my Java program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is what you need.

```
    String TRANSACTION_URL = "http://mon.vip.host.com/reports/podding/Transaction?&defaultDim=Name&defaultDim=Type&metric=TransactionDuration&percentile=95";

    Calendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    Calendar endDate =(Calendar) startDate.clone();
    startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
    String startTime = df.format(startDate.getTime());
    String endTime = df.format(endDate.getTime());

    System.out.println(TRANSACTION_URL+"&startTime="+startTime+"&endTime="+endTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use StringFormat to do it in a nice way:

```
String TRANSACTION_URL = "http://mon.vip.host.com/reports/podding/Transaction?&defaultDim=Name&defaultDim=Type&metric=TransactionDuration&percentile=95&startTime=%s&endTime=%s";

Calendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar();
startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
Calendar endDate =(Calendar) startDate.clone();
startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
String startTime = df.format(startDate.getTime());
String endTime = df.format(endDate.getTime());

System.out.println(String.format(TRANSACTION_URL, startTime , endTime));
```

Comment: I think it should be "String.format(TRANSACTION_URL, startTime , endTime)" ?

Answer (score 0):

An additional remark: The resulting URL is not correct as it contains a space between the date part and time part.

Better to use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd'%20'HH:mm")`; to escape the space. Don't forget the single quotes around the literal text %20.